# Writing multiple array pointers to file with ofstream?

Tags: c++, iostream, ifstream, ofstream

I'm having some seriously strange trouble writing multiple arrays of data to a file. Basically, I'm wanting to store all the array sizes at the top of the file, and then the array data following. This way I can just read the sizes and use that to construct arrays to hold the data on import, and I'll know exactly where each array begins and ends.

Here's the problem: I write the data, but it's different on import. Please take a look at my little test code. At the bottom there are comments about the values.

Thank you very much, fellow programmers! :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    int     jcount = 100, // First item in file
            kcount = 200, 
            in_jcount,    // Third item in file. jcount is used to find where this ends.
            in_kcount;

    float   *j = new float[jcount],
            *k = new float[kcount],
            *in_j,
            *in_k;

    for(int i = 0; i < jcount; ++i) // Write bologna data...
        j[i] = (float)i;
    for(int i = 0; i < kcount; ++i)
        k[i] = (float)i;

    std::ofstream outfile("test.dat");

    outfile.write((char*)&jcount, sizeof(int)); // Good
    outfile.tellp();

    outfile.write((char*)&kcount, sizeof(int)); // Good
    outfile.tellp();

    outfile.write((char*)j, sizeof(float) * jcount); // I don't know if this works!
    outfile.tellp();

    outfile.write((char*)k, sizeof(float) * kcount); // I don't know if this works!
    outfile.tellp();

    outfile.close();


    std::ifstream in("test.dat");

    in.read((char*)&in_jcount, sizeof(int));    // == jcount == 100, good.
    in.read((char*)&in_kcount, sizeof(int));    // == kcount == 200, good.

    in_j = new float[in_jcount],
    in_k = new float[in_kcount];    // Allocate arrays the exact size of what it should be

    in.read((char*)in_j, sizeof(float) * in_jcount);    // This is where it goes bad!
    in.read((char*)in_k, sizeof(float) * in_kcount);

    float   jtest_min = j[0],   // 0.0
            jtest_max = j[jcount - 1],  // this is 99.

            ktest_min = k[0],   // 0.0
            ktest_max = k[kcount - 1],  // this is 200. Why? It should be 199!

            in_jtest_min = in_j[0], // 0.0
            in_jtest_max = in_j[in_jcount - 1], // 99

            in_ktest_min = in_k[0], // 0.0
            in_ktest_max = in_k[in_kcount - 1]; // MIN_FLOAT, should be 199. What is going on here?

    in.close();

    delete k;
    delete j;
    delete in_j;
    delete in_k;
}
```

Comment: This is not answering your question but I just wanted to point out that if you initialize an object with `new[]` you should destroy it with `delete[]`. Also, just a quick question: did you have a look at `test.dat` to see if it wrote out all the arrays properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing obviously wrong with this code (indeed, I don't see the errors you're encountering when I try running it), except for the fact that you are not checking for errors opening the input/output files.

For example, if you don't have permission to write to "test.dat", the open will silently fail, and you'll read back in whatever happened to be in the file before.

Comment: You mean it executes perfectly on your computer? You get the same array of data as it should come out?

Comment: This is very strange. I just restarted my PC and the code is executing perfectly, as it should. Sorry for the bother :x unsafe code is indeed unsafe.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I've run this with g++ on both OS X and Linux, and it gets back exactly the same values that were written out. So: check for errors opening the output file; check the modification date on the file to verify that you're really writing to it; dump out the contents of the file (with a tool like `od -f` on Linux) to see what's been written.

Comment: For some reason I am encountering this problem again, despite multiple reboots and tests for valid file reading/writing. This question is yet unanswered... :(

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same bug, I fix it by using binary file:

```
ofstream outfile;
outfile.open ("test.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
```

and

```
ifstream in;
in.open ("test.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);
```