# write pointer array to a file

Tags: c++

I would like to know how can I write a pointer array:

```
short* myArray
```

and a pointer

```
short[] myArray
```

to a file in C++?

Comment: you want to write adresses or objects pointed by pointers?

Comment: I want to write the values of the array

Comment: Iterate over the array and write each value then.

Comment: for short* myArray, how can I get the length of it? size(myArray) seems not correct

Comment: @olidev, if you are passing the array to a function to print, the array decays to a pointer so `sizeof(myArray)` will be size of a `short*`. You need to pass in the number of elements. Also, as this C++ suggest using a `std::vector<short>` or `std::array`.

Comment: You need to keep track of the size of the array

Comment: `short* myArray` declares a pointer, not an array, and `short[] myArray` declares an arrya, not a pointer. Can you show an example of what the file should look like?

Comment: This is one of the reasons why containers (e.g. std::vector and std::array) should be preferred over arrays: they have a size() method.

Comment: look at this.It should help you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351718/writing-multiple-array-pointers-to-file-with-ofstream

Comment: Honestly this is such a basic question that in lack of a more specific requirement I have to downvote as poor basic research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [ofstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ofstream/) class for this. Open the file with the [open()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ofstream/open/) method, then iterate through the array and use the `<<` operator to write each short to the file.

You can get the size of the array (`short[] array`) by doing

```
int arraySize = sizeof(array) / sizeof(short);
```

while for the pointer (`short* array`) you need to keep track yourself of the size of the array it points to.

Comment: A somewhat better way of getting the size is `template<typename T, size_t N> size_t size( T (&array)[N] ) { return N; }`.  If you don't have an array (but only a pointer), this will fail to compile, rather than give the wrong answer.

Answer (score 3):

example:

```
char phrase[30]="whatever\n";
```

`phrase` is a pointer already. For compiler to access string, it accesses memory location of start of string so:

`phrase[0]=*phrase` and this is w character in memory, address is given by pointer phrase (ok we are calling it a string array, but it really is a pointer, only a string array when specified as 
`phrase[30]`.
so if phrase is memory address of start of array - character `w` then
`(phrase+1)` is memory address for character h, given by `*(phrase+1)` same as `phrase[1]`
and `(phrase+2)` is memory address for character a, given by `*(phrase+2)` same as `phrase[2]`
etc....